# Returning MAX Value for a Respective Name From ContactsLog to Contacts Sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel I have two sheets:

- Contacts
- ContactsLog

The sheet Contacts contains **distinct** contacts. Column B contains the name of the contact, for example 'Doe, John'.

The sheet ContactsLog contains records about every interaction with contact and the respective date when the contact was contacted. The respective date is stored in the column 'Contact Date'.

I would like to have another column in the sheet 'Contacts' called 'Last Contact Date'. How can I write a formula which looks up the name of the contact in the 'Contacts' sheet, finds all the records about the interaction of that particular contact, and brings be back the most recent data from the 'Contact Date' column, and writes it back into 'Last Contact Date' column?

I appreciate your help.

Best wishes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume the names are in Column A on their respective sheets and the dates are in Column C.

If you have Office 365 Excel, Use MAXIFS():

```
=MAXIFS(Sheet2!C:C,Sheet2!A:A,A2)
```

If you have 2010 or later use Aggregate():

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,Sheet2!C2:C100/(Sheet2!A2:A100 = A2),1)
```

If niether use MAX(IF()) as an array formula.:

```
=MAX(IF(Sheet2!A2:A100 = A2,Sheet2!C2:C100))
```

Confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: many thanks Scott! Works perfectly. If someone is interested, here is the formula from my Excel sheet =MAX(IF(ContactLog!$B$5:$B$27 = A6;ContactLog!$A$5:$A$27))