# Find the highest number with a condition

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make a macro in VBA which I input "Cliente" number and it'll find in this table the highest "Aditivo" number which matches with "Cliente" number.

For exemple:

If I input "5", it should return "6"
If I input "3", it should return "5"

[image]

Comment: Why vba, when a simple formula will accomplish this?

Comment: `=MaxIfs()` would do the job nicely.

Comment: here is question similar to yours that shows the formulas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46621384/returning-max-value-for-a-respective-name-from-contactslog-to-contacts-sheet

Comment: It've to be in VBA because I'm doing all my code in VBA

Comment: @HeitorBadotti - Then use `MAXIFS()` in VBA?

Comment: Sorry, I was replying Scott... Nice! I didn't know about this function... I'll try it and post results here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others said, you can get away with a worksheet formula. But if VBA needs be, well... use a worksheet formula anyways:

Give this a try:

```vb
Sub findHighestNo()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim lRow As Long
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim max_rng As Range
Set max_rng = ws.Range("B1:B" & lRow)

Dim cliente: cliente = InputBox("Select your cliente ID")
Dim Result

'    If IsNumeric(cliente) Then
'
'        Result = WorksheetFunction.MaxIfs(max_rng, max_rng.Offset(, -1), cliente)
'        MsgBox Result, vbInformation, "Max result"
'    Else
'        MsgBox "Input a number instead!"
'    End If

Dim arrData As Variant
arrData = max_rng.Offset(, -1).Resize(, 2)
Dim arrTmp() As Long: ReDim arrTmp(1 To lRow)

    If IsNumeric(cliente) Then
        Dim R As Long
        For R = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
            If arrData(R, 1) = CLng(cliente) Then
                arrTmp(R) = arrData(R, 2)
            End If
        Next R

        Result = WorksheetFunction.Max(arrTmp)
        MsgBox Result, vbInformation, "Max result"
    Else
        MsgBox "Input a number instead!"
    End If

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** Added an alternative to get `MAX`, as `MAXIFS` is only available in [Office 365 / 2019](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883).

Comment: I tried to upload it but it says to me "Unable to get the MaxIfs property of the WorksheetFunction Class"

Comment: Uhm... this seems to be available in [Office 365 / 2019](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883) +. Assuming you are using an older version of Excel?

Comment: @HeitorBadotti that seems to be up to date. You still get this error if you use this? `Sub testmaxifs(): MsgBox WorksheetFunction.MaxIfs(Range("A1"), Range("A2"), 100): End Sub` (simplest i can think off to test).

Comment: Ok, I updated my Excel, it was 2016 now it's 2019... Now I've the MaxIfs formula... I'll use it... Thanks a lot... Didn't know the new excel have tons of more formulas..

Comment: Great stuff @HeitorBadotti, if it does the job for you, please do accept the answer :)